# drag на мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка

Здравствуйте, надо реализовать на мобильных телефонах перетаскивание блоков пальцем, до этого находил drag плагины которые работали только на десктопах где есть мышка, кто может подсказать какой-то плагин с помощью которого можно это реализовать? Ниже наглядный пример[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это обычная карусель?

Comment: Посмотри эту тему, должно спасти https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172100/html-drag-and-drop-on-mobile-devices